# Replace Json key in Karate

Tags: karate

I need to send a Json to an endpoint but I need to replace a key with a variable.

I've this code

```
 .....  

  * def idJson = response.id

  Given path <mypath>
  And headers {Authorization: '#(auth)'}
  And request read('classpath:myjson.json')
  .....
```

The myjson.json file is

{
"a":
{
...
"b":false,
"c":true
},
"d":
{
**'#(idJson)'**:
{
"Key":[
.....
]
}
}
}

But the value is not replace in the json. When I perform the request I see that the json contains the string '#(idJson)' instead of the value of the variable. Any idea about how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: just edited my answer after seeing you meant json "key"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded expressions cannot be used to modify a JSON key. You have to use a JS operation like this:

```
* def idJson = 'foo'
* def body = {}
* body[idJson] = 'bar'
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* request body
* method post
* status 200
* match response.json == { foo: 'bar' }
```

Note that `d` could be replaced like this so you can still read the file and be dynamic:

```
{ "d": "#(temp)" }
```

And `temp` can be JSON that is defined in your feature before reading the file.

If this is too troublesome, please contribute code :)

Comment: Thank you, with your suggestion I was able to implement this.